# Fix error on postfix (Build to smtp server)

Tags: postfix, email-server

I setup postfix as

```
command_directory = /usr/local/sbin
config_directory = /usr/local/etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/local/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/db/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
html_directory = /usr/local/share/doc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/local/bin/mailq
manpage_directory = /usr/local/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain,
mydomain = abc.com.au
myhostname = cdb.au
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/local/bin/newaliases
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/local/share/doc/postfix
sample_directory = /usr/local/etc/postfix
sendmail_path = /usr/local/sbin/sendmail
setgid_group = maildrop
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

Then , i add user to system. When sent mail on microsoft outlook,I get error 
THis is log in /var/log/maillog.

> hostname aaaaa verification failed: hostname nor servname provided, or
>   not known Nov  1 16:59:47 cdb postfix/smtpd[14405]: connect from
>   unknown[193.99.3.223]

Comment: Try to refrain from telling people to "Help me." We're not paid support technicians.

Comment: Please include the output of `postconf -n` and relevant mail logs, at minimum showing the path of an entire message through the postfix system.

Answer (score 1):

This is no error. This is a notification.

It tells you that your DNS resolution is broken for your hostname "aaaa". Either you have no PTR for IP 193.99.3.223 or the PTR of 193.99.3.223 does not match the hostname "aaaa". Fix it and the notification will go away.

Answer (score 0):

You got mydomain and myhostname mixed up. It should be this:

```
mydomain = com.au
myhostname = abc.cdb.au
```